# Prohibition to eat blood

Tags: halacha, commentaries, blood, tzav

[Leviticus 7:26-27](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.7.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) teach us about the prohibition to eat blood, whether it be of fowl or of beast, in any of the dwellings.

So is one allowed to eat the blood of the fish? 
Is one allowed to eat blood outside of our dwellings? 
Is one allowed to drink the blood (seperated from the meat)? 
And last but not least am I allowed to suck the blood up of the bleeding finger of my child?

Comment: I think it applies to blood in general, no matter when, how and where.

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91921/9682

Comment: @mbloch from where do we know that drinking in any circumstances isn’t allowed?

Comment: @Y.Talmid see e.g., [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968262/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-6.htm) or [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/838386/jewish/Is-Human-Blood-Kosher.htm)

Comment: related: [Is it allowed to suck blood from a wound?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100217/11501)

Answer (score 3):

In regards to eating the blood of a fish, the Rambam in Mishnah Torah, [Ma'achalos Asuros 6:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Foods.6.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> אֲבָל **דַּם דָּגִים** וַחֲגָבִים וּשְׁקָצִים וּרְמָשִׂים וְדַם הָאָדָם אֵין חַיָּבִין עָלָיו מִשּׁוּם דָּם. **לְפִיכָךְ דַּם דָּגִים** וַחֲגָבִים טְהוֹרִים **מֻתָּר לְאָכְלוֹ וַאֲפִלּוּ כְּנָסוֹ בִּכְלִי וְשָׁתָהוּ מֻתָּר.**
>
> But the **blood of fish** and grasshoppers, and *shkatzim* and *ramasim* and the blood of a human, one hasn't violated the prohibition of consuming blood. **Thus the blood of the fish**   and *tahor* grasshoppers **are permitted to eat, even if one gathered it into a vessel and drank it**

The Shulchan Aruch ([YD 66:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.66.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) codifies this but only allows it if a certain condition is met:

> דם דגים אף על פי שהוא מותר אם קבצו בכלי אסור משום מראית עין לפיכך אם ניכר שהוא מדגים כגון שיש בו קשקשים מותר:
>
> The blood of fish even though it is permitted if they are collected in a vessel is forbidden because of appearances, so if it is clear that it demonstrates such as having scales allowed

**Bottom line**: it's allowed provided you drink it with fins/ scales near it so there would be no issue of "*maras ayin.*"