# Is it allowed to suck blood from a wound?

Tags: halacha, choleh-sick, blood

A natural reaction when cutting oneself (e.g., on a finger) is to suck out the blood. However the Torah writes ([Vayikra 17:12-14](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.17.12?lang=bi&aliyot=0) and other places)

> "עַל־כֵּן אָמַרְתִּי לִבְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל כָּל־נֶפֶשׁ מִכֶּם לֹא־תֹאכַל דָּם וְהַגֵּר הַגָּר בְּתוֹכְכֶם **לֹא־יֹאכַל דָּם**׃ "
>
> Therefore I say to the Israelite people: No person among you shall partake of blood, nor shall the stranger who resides among you partake of blood.

Is it forbidden to suck a wound? Is that considered "eating the blood"?

Comment: It is not about sucking, it's about swallowing I think. Sucking and spitting is OK. Add this to your answer.

Comment: Sucking and spitting might still be an issue of *marit ayin* if people don't see you spit. And frankly it is not so common nowadays to spit things. I am really asking if it is permissible to suck knowing most people will then swallow rather than spit

Comment: BTW what's the benefit of sucking? If it's purely medical it overrides the Maris Ayn. So sucking and spitting is just right.

Comment: I can't speak of others but for me it is to avoid having blood over my fingers and putting it all over the place afterwards

Comment: So that would be Maris ayn vs what? If it's as worthy as I proposed that would be allowed. I think MA only applies for common practices. Sucking blood is not so common, at least here in Israel.

Comment: @AlBerko So I can suck milk when I'm eating meat and spit it out, and it's not an issue of basar b'chalav?

Comment: @ezra the OP already answered that the human blood itself is not prohibited, and that's different from בשר וחלב that are prohibited together.

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me recently so I looked (post facto) for the answer.

R David Sperling gives background [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=5984)

> The Shulchan Aruch ([Yoreh De'ah 66:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.66.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) states that human blood, after
> it has left the body, is forbidden. This is not because the human
> blood itself is forbidden to us from the Torah, but rather because
> someone might think mistakenly that it was non-human blood and
> therefore forbidden (*marit aiyin*).
>
> So, if
> one bites an apple and finds that blood has come out of one's gums
> onto the apple, the blood spots must be removed from the apple before
> taking the next bite. However, continues the Shulchan Aruch, blood
> inside one's mouth is allowed, and so if one has bit their cheek, or
> has bleeding gums, the blood inside the mouth may be swallowed, and
> one does not need to spit it out.

There are two opinions regarding blood from a wound:

1. Some (following [Tosafot](https://www.sefaria.org/Keritot.21b.45?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Keritot.21b.45.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en), e.g., Orach Mishor, [Kaf Hachayim](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.67?lang=bi&p2=Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.66.47.1&lang2=bi)), say that it is permissible to suck it as it is clearly human blood that has not separated from the body
2. Others (following [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.60a.9?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Ketubot.60a.9.1&lang2=bi), e.g., Nachal Eshkol, Minchat Yaakov) rule strictly that only blood inside the mouth which others cannot see can be swallowed

For more details and sources see [here](https://eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=189&article=657) from Eretz Chemda and [Nishmat Avraham](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/NI2H.html) vol. 2, p. 16.

Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734). Mine ruled strictly that one shouldn't suck it once it has left the wound and is visible to others.

Comment: I was always looking for this Tosfos you quoted from Krisus when i was learning Kesubos, and ive finnaly seen it thanks to your research