# Does אונאת דברים include disgusting someone?

Tags: halacha

Does the issur of Onaas D'varim include disgusting someone? or eating in a way that can disgust someone

Comment: To clarify- are you asking if such behavior is forbidden? Or do you specifically want to know if it falls under the halachic category of Onaas Devarim? The gemara and poskim do discuss not coughing up phlegm and not picking lice in front of other people (I'll try to find the source); I'm not sure if it specifically fits that particular prohibition. What's your focus here?

Comment: Note there is a halacha known as *Bal Teshaktzu* which prohibits from engaging in any activity that could be viewed as disgusting. See for instance [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91922/11501) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92015/11501).

Answer (score 2):

Not foolproof but the gemarra in [Chagigah 5a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.5a.11) may imply not.

> רבי יוחנן כי מטי להאי קרא בכי (קהלת יב, יד) כי את כל מעשה האלהים יביא במשפט על כל נעלם
>
> Additionally, when Rabbi Yoḥanan reached this verse, he cried: “For God shall bring every work into the judgment concerning every hidden thing” (Ecclesiastes 12:14).
>
> מאי על כל נעלם אמר רב זה ההורג כינה בפני חברו ונמאס בה ושמואל אמר זה הרק בפני חבירו ונמאס
>
> The Gemara asks: What sin is the verse referring to when it states: “Concerning every hidden thing”? Rav said: This is referring to one who kills a louse in the presence of another and his friend is disgusted by it. God judges him for the unintentional discomfort he caused. And similarly, Shmuel said: This is referring to one who spits in the presence of another and his friend is disgusted by his action.

You see disgusting another is called על כל נעלם. Rashi [there](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Chagigah.5a.11.1) explains:

> על כל - אפי' דבר מועט במשמע:
>
> Upon everything. Even a small thing is implied.

If disgusting another was a biblical prohibition, I wouldn't call it a "small thing".